# dataframe: forward fill next n rows on condition

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0]})
```

I want to have a rolling function where if the value of 1 appears, the next 5 rows will flip to 0.

I think it'll be have to an iterative process, but not sure how best to implement it.

This is the desired df using the above rule.

```
df_desired = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]})
```

Thanks

F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to do this, you'll want to find all the indices of df that are equal to 1 and then find all the indices that are greater than 5 apart from each other consecutively.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0]})
ind = df[df['Col1'] == 1].index #get the indices where df == 1

#find all the indices that are consecutively greater than 5 apart
val = [ind[0]]
for k in ind[1:]:
    if k - val[-1] > 5:
        val.append(k)

df['Col1'] = 0 #change all the values to zero
df['Col1'][val] = 1 #change all indices where there was spaced ones to 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to what has already been provided. This just iterates through the data frame. Each time it encounters a 1, it will start flipping the next 5 elements to 0.

```
import pandas as pd
no_of_flips = 5
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0]})
df_desired = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]})

for inx in df.index:
    if i > 0:
        df.at[inx, 'Col1'] = 0
        i -= 1
    if df.loc[inx,'Col1'] == 1:  
        i = no_of_flips

if (df.compare(df_desired)).empty:
    print('Both dataFrames are the same!')
else:
    print('Dataframes are different')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```
i = 0
while i < (len(list) - 5):

    if list[i] == 1:
        list[i+1:i+6] = [0]*5
        i += 6

    i += 1
print(list)
```

You just replace the slice of the next 5 values with 0's. ([0]*5 creates such an array). Then you skip by 6 if you replaced, otherwise just by the usual 1.

Of course you need to convert to a list first using pd.Series.tolist(). Then you can add it back